# Angular alphabetizes GET response

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, node.js, express

I am currently trying to make an interactive table in Angular that reflects table information from a SQL database.

The stack I am using is MSSQL, Express.js, and AngularJS. When I log the response in Node, the data is in the desired order. However, when I log the data from `.success(function(data))`, the fields are alphabetized and the rows are put in random order).

I am sending a JSON object (an array of rows EX. `{"b":"blah","a":"aye"}`). However the row is received in Angular as `{"a":"aye","b":"blah"}`.

**Desired affect** -> Use column and row ordering from SQL query in client view. Remove "magic" angular is using to order information.

Comment: are you 100% sure its angular doing this and not the server or some UI widget?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the properties of an object do not have guaranteed order. You need to send a JSON array instead:

```
["blah", "aye"]
```

If you need the column names as well you can send down an array of objects:

```
[{ "col":"b", "value":"blah" }, { "col":"a", "value":"aye" }]
```

Or alternatively, an object of arrays:

```
{ "col": ["b", "a"], "value": ["blah", "aye"] }
```

**Edit:** After some more thought, you're ideal JSON structure would probably look like this:

```
{
  "col": ["b","a"],
  "row": [
    ["blah","aye"],
    ["second","row"],
    ["and","so on"]
  ]
}
```

Now instead of getting "blah" from accessing `table[0]['b']` like you would've before, you'll need to do something like `table.row[0][table.col.indexOf('b')]`

Comment: thank you for your response. I now see the problem with Javascript objects. Unfortunately, this still does not preserve row ordering. I need both row and column preservation.